# How to edit contact data in Android

Tags: android, contacts

I have an app which allows user to edit contacts. And in that app I have Me contact, problem is when I try to edit it, by retrieving uri of me contact, it always returns NULL. Is there any way to edit Me contact programmatically?

Comment: can you post the code that you are trying to use now?